# how to enable persistence storage in firebase in flutter apps?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am kinda stuck in my project trying to figure out how to enable the persistence data in flutter apps.

How can we do this, I have seen the example on github [example here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/68bb455086279dd11b32d5791a4b2321d46a3340/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart).

But, how can i check if there is any internet connection and if no how can i display the data from the firebase cache stored on the device.

Please, can someone tell me how can i achieve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Mahi

Comment: As far as I know that's the default behavior. You shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: hi @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the reply yes it is enabled by default but is there a way that i could use this kind of concept for the http triggers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't undestand what you mean with "this kind of concept" or "http triggers"

Comment: sorry about that, I was thinking to store the data from http triggers locally and display it back to the user when in offline mode. I think we can use SharedPreferences to do this but is there any other better solution.

Comment: There us a cinnectivity plugin that allows to check if there is a network connection.You need to make actual requests to see uf the network is connected with the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much @GünterZöchbauer for your help. Yes I've looked at the plugin and i need to change my code accordingly. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the persistence is enabled by default as described by @GunterZochbauer for firebase and we dont need to do anything regarding this.

Thanks,
Mahi